# If-else condition for insert inside trigger (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

[image]

Above is the code I want my trigger to execute.

Below is the error it shows:

[image]

While this won't work, simply putting a simple if condition works well. Such as:

```
IF (OLD.description <> NEW.description) THEN
    INSERT INTO tbl_users_log (detail) 
    VALUES(CONCAT('description: ',OLD.description,'->', NEW.description));
END IF
```

Answer (score 0):

You used 'ELSE IF' actually its 'ELSEIF'

```
IF (OLD.description <> NEW.description) THEN
  INSERT INTO tbl_users_log (detail) 
  VALUES(CONCAT('description: ',OLD.description,'->', NEW.description));
ELSEIF IF (NEW.prefix <> OLD.prefix) THEN
   INSERT INTO tbl_users_log (detail) 
   VALUES(CONCAT('yourData: ',OLD.prefix,'->', NEW.prefix));
END IF
```

Comment: The problem with the code is the structure of IF-ELSE-THEN not being accepted in the trigger. Everything else within it (INSERT query) works fine. But, I'll surely try to do this code with the three INSERT queries.

Comment: Hey, I got your question. You used 'ELSE IF'  actually it  'ELSEIF'.